# jQuery css display problem with I.E

Tags: jquery

I have this code to display->block or none when click one of them:

```
$('#kktekcekimid').click(function(){
    $('#efthavale').css('display','none');  
    $('#kapida').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikarti').css('display','block');    
    $('#kredikartitaksit').css('display','none');   
    $('#odemetipi').attr('value','kktekcekim'); 
});

$('#kktaksitid').click(function(){
    $('#efthavale').css('display','none');  
    $('#kapida').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikarti').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikartitaksit').css('display','block');
    $('#odemetipi').attr('value','kktaksitli'); 
}); 

$('#havaleeftid').click(function(){
    $('#efthavale').css('display','block'); 
    $('#kapida').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikarti').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikartitaksit').css('display','none');
    $('#odemetipi').attr('value','havaleeft');  
}); 

$('#kapidaodemeid').click(function(){   

    $('#kapida').css('display','block');
    $('#efthavale').css('display','none');  
    $('#kredikarti').css('display','none'); 
    $('#kredikartitaksit').css('display','none');
    $('#odemetipi').attr('value','kapidapesin');    
});
```

and this is default html code which  includes divs above:

```
<input id="radioDefault_2" name="Fieldss" type="hidden" value="" /> 
<span> 
<input id="kktekcekimid" name="Field2" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Online Kredi Kartı" <?php echo $kktekcekim_value;?> tabindex="5" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" required /> 
<label class="choice" for="kktekcekimid" > 
Online Kredi Kartı <strong>Tek Çekim</strong></label> 
</span> 
<span> 
<input id="kktaksitid" name="Field2" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Online Kredi Kartı" <?php echo $kktaksitli_value;?> tabindex="5" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" required /> 
<label class="choice" for="kktaksitid" > 
Online Kredi Kartı <strong>Taksitli</strong></label> 
</span>
<span> 
<input id="havaleeftid" name="Field2" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Havale/EFT" <?php echo $havaleft_value;?> tabindex="6" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" required /> 
<label class="choice" for="havaleeftid" > 
Havale/EFT</label> 
</span> 
<span> 
<input id="kapidaodemeid" name="Field2" type="radio" class="field radio" value="Kapıda Peşin" <?php echo $kapidapesin_value;?> tabindex="7" onchange="handleInput(this);" onmouseup="handleInput(this);" required /> 
<label class="choice" for="kapidaodemeid" > 
Kapıda Peşin</label> 
</span>

<div id="efthavale" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="kapida" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="kredikarti" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="kredikartitaksit" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="kisiselbilgiler" style="display:block"></div>
```

This works on chrome and firefox. But on ie, it always shows  as default and does not show other divs when click. (and does not hide id="kredikarti" style="display:none" div.)

And also it never displays this div as default:  id="kisiselbilgiler" style="display:block"

What can be the problem?

Comment: I just wanted to congratulate you for making your code so readable, despite the fact that I can't understand one word of Turkish. :-)

Comment: I.E does not handle anyting useful and 50% people use this bullshit. I will kill Bill :) 

This is the answer...

Comment: can anybody tell me if it is legal to write here these script's adress?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with? I tested your code in IE 9 and it works the same as Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/P2mpF/

Comment: I noticed another issue though - you have functions on your onmouseup and onchange events for each input that aren't defined in this code (handleInput). If that function isn't defined, it could definitely cause issues in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the solution you are looking for, but instead of hiding it in the css inline styles hide it this way:

```
 $('#efthavale, #kapida, etc').hide();
```

Also, make sure that you are surrounding the jQuery in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: thanks but show & hide is not working. It's a worse solution than css (for these spagetti codes).

Comment: I am talking about to replace the `style="display:none"` inside the div.

Comment: I can't change " display:none " because it is conditioned in php:

  case '':
   $kktekcekim_display = 'display:none';

and 
                break;

<div id="kredikarti" style="<?php echo $kktekcekim_display;?>">

Comment: ah, because that might be an issue with IE. Can you edit the `PHP` at all? Because you can, instead of adding `display:none`, just add a class and hide that class with the `hide()`

Comment: @Phil - that won't cause a problem in IE at all. That's the standard (and correct) way to have something hidden by default that you want jQuery to control. If you call .hide() on load, then the div will show up at first and then disappear - poor user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. None of your `<div>` tags at the bottom have closing `</div>` tags. But Phil is also correct that you should use `.hide()` and `.show()`

Comment: Its valid, i've forgot to write only. I changed. (It is not an html problem)

Answer (score 1):

you should make your code a little more simple like this: :)

```
$(':radio').click(function(){
   $(this).show();
   hideall();
    $('#odemetipi').attr('value', $(this).val()); 
});

function hideall(){
   $(".derp div").hide();
}

<div class="derp">
   <div id="efthavale" style="display:none"></div>
   <div id="kapida" style="display:none"></div>
   <div id="kredikarti" style="display:none"></div>
   <div id="kredikartitaksit" style="display:none"></div>
   <div id="kisiselbilgiler" style="display:block"></div>
</div>
```